# Price optimisation with multipliers - how to optimise based on price when each section has a multiplier?

Tags: php, excel, optimization, vba

I have an assignment at work that involves finding the solution to this difficult problem.

Customers here can buy product allocations in either daily, monthly, quarterly or yearly amounts. Each step has a multiplier associated with it to incentivise people to book the longest allocation, so for example a day = 1.5 times the unit price, quarter = 1.3, month=1.2 etc.

This was fine, however, now they would like to see if having a different multiplier per step (i.e month 1 = 1.5, month 2 = 1.2, month 3 = 1.4 etc) down to monthly resolution.

In this case, the base case is year = 1, and daily = 1.5 with monthly and quarterly multipliers set inbetween.

My task is to get the perfect optimisation of each step to minimise the bill (we are simulating what a buyer will do) according to a demand profile.

So to sum up I need to find the minimum price a buyer could get while still meeting their demand profile.

Here's an example of the sort of demand chart I'm working with, with each yearly division shown where the multipliers are equal to 1 (the base case)
[image: images]

I'm working with either **VBA, Python, PHP, or C** for this. Preferably VBA (what work wants) or PHP (what I want) but in any case, it' the general case I don't get. Just how would I even start going about this price optimisation?? Will it be a case of literally simulating EVERY case? (of which there are 131,071 [year divides into 12 months, 4 seasons, 1 year + 12 months + 4 seasons + 1 daily multiplier = 18, 2^18=262144, divide by 2 because in every case they will buy days and minus 1 for the null case]).

Thanks to anyone who can help,even just a little bit!

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to the packaging problem and knapsack problems? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

If you consider each month as a package size, then you are after the best fit to a total demand. Just with the added twist of first package fitting for a year, then for 5months, then for 4 months etc. These algorithms are surprisingly quick even considering the brute force like nature, and they are also nice and decomposable to multiple processors if needed?
(sorry this isn't just a comment, I'm not able to comment yet, or don't know how..)
(thinking more, perhaps FFT might also be useable here, but I'm not an expert in that)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is indeed a bit like the knapsack problem...I believe you are right I'm going to have to brute force it.

I did think about FFT and we ran an analysis quickly in excel but we have to base the data on the previous year only (required by law for my business) so the spatial resolution isn't high enough for it to be accurate (FFT is ~ 10-15% off the mark in this case, which isn't good enough).

Comment: One possible wrinkle, aren't you better slightly overbuying rather than purchasing at the daily rate? Your graph at around 40 days shows fit under the line, but potentially buy 30% or some more would save money over the whole month. Also, you might get more answers in http://stats.stackexchange.com for methods, but not code.

Comment: Thanks rlb - that's exactly my point, in the case where the multiplier for a day is more than a month, that is certainly the case. Then you just buy days where you need to meet the extra demand and overall save money.

In the picture is the 'base' case where the price per unit when you purchase a month is the same as per day, hence the optimisations is simply the graph shown above.

My problem is how to work out the optimisation programatically, but I think it's just a matter of brute forcing to find a local minimum.